# Resource to read about distributions

Tags: distributions, references

My course textbook for statistics is the one by Levine and Smith. However, I find myself interested in the various probability distributions. The author simply states the $f_X(x)$ and  derives $F_X(x)$ and gives an application. I was in the hunt of a good online (*FREE*) resource which talks about probability distributions in a more intuitive setup. For instance, telling me WHY the equation for exponential, Weibull, Normal, Gamma etc. are the way they are. Especially gamma distribution, he simply states that in the calculus class one can learn to prove that the integral is convergent and states  $f_X(x)$.

Comment: It's a good question, but could you be a little more specific about what kind of information you are looking for? The answers to "why" can range from a description of how a distribution arises in applications through a mathematical explanation of properties of its PDF, CDF, and related functions. What are you looking to learn about Gamma distributions?

Comment: @whuber, just motivation and uses really. I see people say that something is a normal by chi2 by dof and I ask them why did anyone ever try to do such a thing and they have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two more distribution resources.  They are descriptive and present equations, without much proof, application, or even discussion.

From NIST: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm

From Dr. M.P. McLaughlin: http://www.causascientia.org/math_stat/Dists/Compendium.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Look at the series "Distributions in Statistics" by Johnson and Kotz.

> 1. [Continuous Univariate Distributions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471584959), Vol. 1 (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics)
> 2. [Continuous Univariate Distributions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471584940), Vol. 2 (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics)
> 3. [Univariate Discrete Distributions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471272469) (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics)
> 4. [Continuous Multivariate Distributions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471183873), Volume 1, Models and Applications, 2nd Edition

They have a volume on discrete distributions, two volumes on univariate continuous distributions and one on multivariate continuous distributions.  The various statistical encyclopedias are good sources and so is

> [Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470665300), Distribution Theory (Volume 1)

Free online information can be found in Wikipedia or through Google searches. There is a lot of good stuff out there.
From [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=statistical+distributions&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4ADFA_enUS472US476&q=statistical+distributions&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.11922...........0.IpxXDmoPrMI)
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution)

Comment: This is a good resource but the OP says `I was in the hunt of a good online (FREE) `.

Comment: Thanks Procrastinator I missed that.  I still like good old fashion bound books written by the masters.

Comment: OK, I have included some links for completeness. (+1)

Comment: @Procrastinator Thanks.  While you did that I was adding the google and wikipedia links.  Got stopped by your edit . But it is all there now!

Comment: It is noteworthy--and, I'm afraid, not very amusing--that acquiring this short list of (excellent) books would run about $1000 US.  Perhaps one reason they are still so expensive is that the usual online resources aren't anywhere near as good or comprehensive.  (*E.g.*, yesterday I was looking for information about how inverse Gamma distributions might arise in nature--apart from their use as conjugate priors for Normal variances--and found *nothing* in the Wikipedia article.)

Comment: @whuber Add the encyclopedia of statistical science and you more than double that price.  Wiley is going online with their stuff now.  Off topic but important to me, I am loading R and search the cran libraries for the Deming regreesion programs.  I forgot the name of the one you mentioned in my post and don't have a lot of time to search CV for it.

Comment: You don't have to search, Michael: go to the [questions section of your profile page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11032/michael-chernick?tab=questions&sort=newest), link to the question, scroll down to my answer, open the list of comments beneath it, and follow the link you remember.

Comment: @whuber FYI I kind of knew that .  But when I do it it is order by votes. You got me to ordered by most recent. Still I got the second question and not the first.  Then I searched by topic Deming regression and found it more quickly.  I thought I remembered it as mrc but it is mcr.  Couldn't findit in the cran library housed at Carnegie Mellon.  Your link got me to the documentation.  I will read through it to see how to upload.I really need shortcuts.

Comment: Don't know how I missed it!  I found it while searching for mcreg. Thanks @whuber !

Comment: I originally found that package on [RSeek.org](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&q=deming&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=rseek.org%2F&ref=&ss=1349j444881j8) with a search for "deming": it's the third hit.

Comment: Now I am asking on SO about imbedding Deming in the bootstrap and loading my excel data.  They haven't been very helpful so far?  Can you open a chat for me on this Bill?

Comment: @whuber: What did you find about inverse gamma distributions arising in nature?  I vaguely remember that resistance of a synapse might be inverse gamma distributed since conductances add.

Comment: @Michael, I think it would be better for you to open a chat room, because that would give you full control over it. Just visit the [chat area](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and look for the button (at the bottom right) to create a new room.

Comment: @Neil I didn't look too hard.  My inverse-gamma-like distribution arose as a normal mixture of distributions of p-values in a Z test where the null hypothesis is false.